# How to detect if my application closes

Tags: android

I want to save my all data to sdcard when my application closes, i've write a class to save my all data but i cannot detect when/where my aplication close or terminate event so i do not know where should i call my Data save class.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about making your own base class that extends Activity and override the onPause, onStop, and onDestroy methods there, then make your activities extend your new base class?

Comment: The title of this question is misleading, I came here looking for information to know when an Android application is terminated, not an Android Activity.

Answer (score 3):

When your Activity is closed, it's onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy() methods will be called, so simply override one of them and save it there.

Check this out:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I have about 20 activities in my project. Application can be closed any time on these activities. I cannot use activity methods

Comment: Can you post so diagram of you app ? so we can have an idee how it works